# Cannot find the object % because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, ssms, azure-data-factory, dynamics-365

I am trying to write data to an Azure SQL DB with Azure Data Factory. I'm using a Copy Data Task within a For Each that looks through all the rows in an ETL table in the DB. In the pre-copy script, I have

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [master].[dbo].[@{item().DestinationObjectName}]
```

DestinationObjectName being the name of the table that is being loaded in the ETL table. The problem I'm having is that for some of the tables (not all, some work perfectly fine) I am getting the error 'Cannot find the object % because it does not exist or you do not have permissions'. The account I'm using has all the necessary privileges as well. I am able to see the script that is sent to ADF which I have copied into the DB and confirmed this script works sometimes but not every time. If I select top 1000 from the table in question and replace that object for the one in the truncate table script, it works. I'm really at a loss here. Like I said the truncate works for a majority of the tables but not all. I have also double checked that the object names are the exact same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You tagged your question with `dynamics-365`, which product specifically (Business Central, Finance, Operations, Sales, ...) and how are you generating your table names list? Why I ask: Dynamics 365 for Finance has a concept of "[inheritance tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/table-inheritance-overview)". Only the _root tables_ will then exist in the SQL Server database.

Comment: did the `DestinationObjectName` tables all in the master DB?

Comment: What permission does your user have on the database? They need to have ALTER permission on the table, to run the truncate. Or part of the db_owner database role or similar. As what you describe is table specific, it sounds like a permission problem on the table, i.e. they have ALTER permission on some tables, but not others.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved. I had to drop the affected tables and remove the brackets surrounding each in the create table statements and recreate without the brackets. very strange issue.